# jzip installed chrome opening www.searchnu.com/102

Tags: windows-7, zip

I am in pain trying to figure out how to remove www.searchnu.com/102 from chrome after installing jzip on my windows 7.

How can I do that? Is this a virus? I ran a scan and it didn't return anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a browser hijacker/spyware. Try [this](http://www.2-spyware.com/remove-searchnu.html):

First, [change the homepage](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95314):

1. Click the Chrome menu [image: 1] on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings** and then the **Show Home button** checkbox in the **Appearance** section to show it on the browser toolbar.
3. When the **Show Home button** checkbox is selected, a web address appears below it. To make the Homepage button open up a different webpage, click **Change**, delete the www.searchnu.com URL and enter a new link. You can also choose the **New Tab page** as your homepage.

Next, [change the default search engine](http://support.google.com/chrome/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=95653):

1. Click the Chrome menu [image: 1] on the browser toolbar.
2. Select **Settings** and find the **Search** section.
3. Select the search engine you want to use from the menu. If the search engine you want to use doesn't appear in the menu, click **Manage search engines**.
4. In the **Search Engines** dialog that appears, select the search engine that you'd like to use from the list (such as google.com).
5. Click the **Make default** button that appears at the end of the row.
6. Delete the **search results** line from the list.

Finally, install [Malwarebytes Anti-Malware Free](http://www.malwarebytes.org), update it and run a **Full scan** on your system.